# How to find the mean of top 50 rows for a particular column in R dataset

Tags: r

I loaded a csv file in R studio in windows ,and I am trying to find the mean of particular dataset's  ,for first 50 rows.
I am using following syntax

```
mean(sorted[1:50,"my_column"],na.rm=TRUE)
```

But in windows ,I am getting following error

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

It works on other machine though .

Is there any alternative of the above syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the dataset is `tibble` or `data.table`.  We need to extract with `[[`

```
mean(sorted[1:50,][["my_column"]], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

`mean(sorted$my_column[1:50], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: This should work without the comma after 1:50

Comment: My bad, good catch! Removed the comma from my answer so it should work now